# Парсер. Запрос на страницу с категорией товара выдаёт HTML-код главной страницы

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть вот такой код, по итогам работы которого получаем ссылку на категорию товаров. Переход по полученной ссылке корректен, открывает в браузере нужную страницу. Но при запросе по полученной ссылке, выдаёт HTML-код главной страницы. И это, в свою очередь, слегка затрудняет дальнейшее развитие событий, к примеру, получение ссылок на подкатегории.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import random

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'}

def category():
    url = 'https://by.wildberries.ru/'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')  
    category_card = soup.find('ul', class_='menu-burger__main-list')
    category_all = category_card.find_all('li')
    for cat in category_all:
        text = cat.find('a').text
        url = cat.find('a').get('href')
        yield text, url

def choise():
    category_dict = []
    timeout = [1,2,3,4,5]
    sleep(random.choice(timeout))
    for text, url in category():
        category_dict.append({'text': text, 'url': url})
        return category_dict

def input_choise():
    url_category = ''
    category_keys = []
    for i in choise():
        category_keys.append(i['text'])
    while True:
        print("\n".join(category_keys) + '\n\n' )
        enter = input('Введите название категории, из предложенных:')
        if enter in category_keys:      
            break
        else:
            print('Вы допустили ошибку при вводе. Попробуйте ещё раз!!!\n\n')  
    for i in choise():        
        if i['text'] == enter:      
            url_category = i['url']      
    return url_category
```

Собственно, есть желание понять - что сделано не так, и, что нужно сделать, чтобы мой процесс самообучения мог продолжиться=)

**Вообще задумка такая**: пользователю предлагается выбрать какую именно категорию и подкатегорию нужно спарсить. То есть джинсы, из категории "женщинам" и так далее.

Comment: Дело в том, что любая страница открывает там один и тот же код страницы, а потом с помощью javascript формирует основной контент в блоке `<div id="app"></div>` в зависимости от роута. Соответственно ваш парсер, который не умеет работать с javascript, всегда получает код главной страницы.

Comment: с другой стороны, если долго изучать закладку network инструментов разработчика, то можно обратить внимание на загружаемые динамически файлы типа https://wbx-content-v2.wbstatic.net/ru/27379808.json , имя которого подозрительно совпадает с ид товара)))

Comment: Вы не это пытаетесь спарсить https://by.wildberries.ru/webapi/menu/main-menu-by-ru.json ?

Comment: @СергейШашко добавил в описание, что именно хочу сделать. А так, просто изучаю возможности языка и библиотек. Так сказать пробую себя в новой стезе=)

Comment: сайт динамический. BeautifulSoup здесь безсилен. Не того кролика выбрали для ваших экспериментов, на данном этапе вашего  самообучения он вам не по зубам. Ну а если ходите спаристь данный ресурс с минимальными затратами сил то воспользуйтесь Selenium

Comment: @СергейШашко благодарю за совет. Что посоветуете по поводу 'scrapy'? Этот кролик ещё строптивее?)

Comment: Я его не юзал, но слышал краяем уха порог вхождения высок. Меня на данном этапе моего самообучения вполне устраевает requests на статических сайтах плюс BeautifulSoup.  Дополню прошлый комент можно пабробывать requests_html + BeautifulSoup. Под кроликом я имел в виду сайт который вы хотели спарсить :)

Comment: @СергейШашко понял, принял. Ох уж, эти кролики:)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137097/discussion-between---and-).

Comment: https://hackware.ru/?p=7641